# CSS - Center align text with icon

Tags: html, css, icons, vertical-alignment, google-material-icons

Using material icons with CSS, I have the following code that renders a link with icon and text.

```
<a href="#"><i class="material-icons">group_work</i>Groups</a>
```

As you can see in the image below, the text seems to be sinking down.. I would like them to be vertically aligned center together. How can i achieve this?

[image: Icon and Text mis-aliged]

PS. (Not a designer!)

Comment: try to use  .material-icons, .icon-text {
      vertical-align: middle;
    } source:-https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/121

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To vertically center elements, you can use the [`vertical-algin: middle;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) rule. In your case, that would most propably be:

```
.material-icons {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is an example with your dark button:

```css
.material-icons {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<a href="#" class="grey darken-3 btn"><i class="material-icons">group_work</i>Groups</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align`:middle`applied to the icon`i` can be the simplest option but results can be inconsistent.

I have found better results with setting the link to `display:inline-flex` but the dfference is quite subtle.

`vertical-align` can still be used as a fallback for non-supporting browsers.

```css
a {
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
a i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<a href="#" class=""><i class="material-icons">group_work</i>Groups</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="flex"><i class="material-icons">group_work</i>Groups</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<a href="#" class="grey darken-4 btn"><i class="material-icons left">group_work</i>Groups</a>
```

Comment: i have been used **material-icons left** class check it out whether it helps you

Answer (score -1):

```
a {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Will do the trick ;)