# issue with vuetify v-icon

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I cannot understand why my v-icon is elevated, it does not allow me to set margins or padding (or rather they have no effect) and I have the content set to baseline. Help!

```
<v-card-text>
          <v-layout justify-start>
            <div class="address">{{bla bla bla}}</div>
            <v-icon small color="purple">verified_user</v-icon>
            <div class="right-icon loc-info">
              <v-icon>map</v-icon>
              <div>Map</div></div>
            <div class="loc-info"><v-icon>directions</v-icon>
            <div>Directions</div>
            </div>
            <div class="loc-info"><v-icon>share</v-icon>
            <div>Share</div>
            </div>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-icon color="grey">close</v-icon>
          </v-layout>
        </v-card-text>
    ....
    <style>
    .loc-info{
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
.right-icon{
  margin-left: 20%
}
```

All this looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BBxs.png)
[image: Image of the code above]

Answer (score 1):

You are styling container. Try to set vuetify props to `v-icon` such as `mb2` or just add class to `v-icon`.

Comment: What do you mean by `mb2` that is not on the api?

Comment: `mb2` means `$spacer * .5`
Please, check out this link [https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/spacing]

Answer (score 1):

I tried what was suggested here:
[CSS - Center align text with icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979775/css-center-align-text-with-icon)

I was able to modify the built in style provided by vuetify with `v-icon`

`.material-icons { vertical-align: middle }`